# Why REGEX_COUNT with semicolon doesn't work?

Tags: regex, oracle, plsql, obiee

I'm trying to count the number of semicolon separated values in OBIEE.
I'm using the following formula: EVALUATE('REGEXP_COUNT(%1, '';'')', "Bibliographic Details"."Title") It returns an error:
[image]

When I try to use the same formula but change the '';'' with say ''a'' everything works as expected.

I don't recall semicolon being a saved character in REGEX so it's weird to me.

Comment: Well, it works for me (using sqldev, not OBIEE, and just a select regexp_count... from dual). Are you sure of the use of single vs double quotes?

Comment: Are you sure you need single quotes arround `REGEXP_COUNT...`?

Comment: @gsalem -I'm sure. Again, the formula worked completely fine and only caused problems when I changed ''a'' to '';''.

Comment: @Toto - I've tried removing them and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

What I did eventually that gave me the required result:
EVALUATE('REGEXP_COUNT(%1, ''\;'')', "Bibliographic Details"."Title")

For some reason the "\" before the ";" fixed the problem.

Comment: maybe the regexp_count is NOT being evaluated by the DB?